# Resources for learning category theory

Tags: math, haskell, category-theory

I am going to take a course on category theory soon.

What resources can you recommend for learning about it?

What parts are relevant to learn and how do I learn to apply my knowledge?

Comment: I'm not sure this really belongs on SO - category theory is marginally related to haskell, I guess, but until there's a mathy version of SO, I don't think this is on-topic.

Comment: Ain't no "marginally related" about it. A lot of Haskell is based on category theory. See the following: http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Category_theory

Comment: Math Overflow thread: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/903/resources-for-learning-practical-category-theory

Comment: To complete the circle, math.stackexchange thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055390/what-is-the-best-path-to-learn-category-theory-and-type-thoery

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- [Haskell Wikibook chapter on Category Theory](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory) (CT in relation to Haskell)
- [Learning Haskell through Category Theory, and Adventuring in Category Land: Like Flatterland, Only About Categories](http://dekudekuplex.wordpress.com/2009/01/16/learning-haskell-through-category-theory-and-adventuring-in-category-land-like-flatterland-only-about-categories/) (review of some books)
- Dan Piponi's blog: http://blog.sigfpe.com/
- [Abstract Nonsense for Functional Programmers by Edsko de Vries (pdf)](http://www.edsko.net/tcd/talks/cattheory.pdf)

Comment: is the blog category theory? seemed more like real analysis when I read it; maybe a date range would be helpful?

Comment: Wow here's a great post: http://blog.sigfpe.com/2010/03/partial-ordering-of-some-category.html

Answer (score 2):

For a very first meeting with category theory I have had ["A taste of category theory for computer scientists"](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2846&context=compsci) recommended.